# How can I dynamically set the `selected` attribute on an `<option>` tag?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

The Ember [guide on binding data attributes](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/) says that "If you use data binding with a Boolean value, it will add or remove the specified attribute." I'm trying to use this feature to dynamically set the `selected` attributes on `<option>`s. I'm finding that I can dynamically set the `disabled` attribute, but the `selected` attribute is always omitted, no whether the boolean is true or false.

Given this handlebars template:

```
<option disabled={{false}} selected={{false}}>One</option>
<option disabled={{true}} selected={{true}}>Two</option>
```

I get the following HTML:

```
<option>One</option>
<option disabled>Two</option>
```

Why doesn't `selected={{true}}` produce a `selected` attribute in the rendered output?

---

To give a bit more context, I'm following this article on [How to do a select in Ember 2.0](https://balinterdi.com/blog/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20/). Using the method described in that article, I can successfully update the data in the controller when the select `onchange` event fires, but the DOM doesn't update to reflect the change.

I've put together [this ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/579092c9273166e209ab05efaad3c453?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C), which includes two `select` elements. One uses `select={{bool}}`, which doesn't work the way I want it to. The other uses a long-hand `{{#if bool}}...{{else}}...{{/if}}`, which does work but looks terrible.

Comment: `selected` is a property, not an attribute with a value

Comment: Is the problem that you're hardcoding `{{true}}` and `{{false}}`? Your example is a little contrived. Instead of hardcoding `{{true}}` and `{{false}}`, you can hardcode the absence or presence of the `selected` attribute.

Comment: @ChrisPeters I admit that using `{{true}}` and `{{false}}` looks contrived, but I wanted to keep the example simple. The results would be the same if the `{{}}` referenced a computed property which returned `true` or `false`.

Comment: A thought: maybe a `disabled` option cannot also be `selected`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who took the time to post an answer my question. [Sonny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244826/sonny)'s comment pointed me in the right direction:

> `selected` is a property, not an attribute with a value

This was news to me and it sent me down a rabbit-hole of discovery. I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/128850) to be especially helpful.

When I posted the question, I didn't appreciate the difference between attributes and properties. I was expecting to see the `selected` attribute appear in the DOM, but this doesn't happen. I now understand that the `selected` *property* is being correctly set, and the fact that the `<option>` tag doesn't appear in the DOM with a `selected` attribute is of no consequence.

This code snippet helps to illustrate why I was confused. Both of the resulting `<select>` dropdown menus appear the same, with option 2 initially selected. The `selected` attribute does not appear in the DOM when it's set using `selected={{true}}`, but it does appear in the DOM in the other case:

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected={{true}}>2</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
</select>
```

Here's [the same snippet as a Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/35d27dbbf7dd101fa1133d186f537a85?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper which compares you option value to a reference somewhere like

```
<select onchange={{action "countryChanged" value="target.value"}}>
{{#each countries as |country|}}
    <option value={{country.id}} selected={{is-equal country model.address.country_code}}>{{country.name}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

Inside your "Helpers" folder (create if not already there)

create your helper file like "is-equal.js"

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function([lhs, rhs]) {
  return lhs === rhs;
});
```

Which will just compare 2 values and return a boolean, you could also return a classname or whatever you like.

The action sets the user selected value to the model.address.country_code, the helper compares the new values, if the selected value matches the option value selected will get set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the selected option using a variable as seen here: https://gist.github.com/fenichelar/d3cfa5c59783fdbf02d32bcc3b3a028d

Here is the Ember Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/d3cfa5c59783fdbf02d32bcc3b3a028d?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Relevant Code:

**application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  one: false,
  two: true,
  three: false
});
```

**application.hbs**

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option selected={{one}}>One</option>
    <option selected={{two}}>Two</option>
    <option selected={{three}}>Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not true. You don't _need_ the quotes. It should work either way.

Comment: @ChrisPeters You are correct, I have updated my answer to reflect the actual issue.